# Remove the missing values from the rows having greater than 5 missing values and then print the percentage of missing values in each column

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://query.data.world/s/Hfu_PsEuD1Z_yJHmGaxWTxvkz7W_b0')
d= df.loc[df.isnull().sum(axis=1)>5]
d.dropna(axis=0,inplace=True)
print(round(100*(1-df.count()/len(df)),2))
```

i m getting output as

```
Ord_id                 0.00
Prod_id                0.00
Ship_id                0.00
Cust_id                0.00
Sales                  0.24
Discount               0.65
Order_Quantity         0.65
Profit                 0.65
Shipping_Cost          0.65
Product_Base_Margin    1.30

dtype: float64
```

but the output is

```
Ord_id                 0.00
Prod_id                0.00
Ship_id                0.00
Cust_id                0.00
Sales                  0.00
Discount               0.42
Order_Quantity         0.42
Profit                 0.42
Shipping_Cost          0.42
Product_Base_Margin    1.06

dtype: float64
```

Comment: can you create a small example to replicate the issue? Right now its not very clear(IMO) as to what exactly you're trying to achieve. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
df.drop(df[df.isnull().sum(axis=1)>5].index,axis=0,inplace=True)

print(round(100*(1-df.count()/len(df)),2))
```

Comment: instead of `print(round(100*(1-df.count()/len(df)),2))` use `df.isnull().sum()`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to find the **index of rows** with null values sum greater 5. Use `np.where` instead of `df.loc` to find the index and then drop them.

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('https://query.data.world/s/Hfu_PsEuD1Z_yJHmGaxWTxvkz7W_b0')
d = np.where(df.isnull().sum(axis=1)>5)
df= df.drop(df.index[d])
print(round(100*(1-df.count()/len(df)),2))
```

output:

```
Ord_id                 0.00
Prod_id                0.00
Ship_id                0.00
Cust_id                0.00
Sales                  0.00
Discount               0.42
Order_Quantity         0.42
Profit                 0.42
Shipping_Cost          0.42
Product_Base_Margin    1.06
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work

```py
df = df[df.isnull().sum(axis=1) <= 5]
print(round(100*(1-df.count()/len(df)),2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  this solution

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://query.data.world/s/Hfu_PsEuD1Z_yJHmGaxWTxvkz7W_b0')
df = df[df.isnull().sum(axis=1)<=5]
print(round(100*(df.isnull().sum()/len(df.index)),2))
```

Answer (score 0):

This Should work.

```py
df = df.drop(df[df.isnull().sum(axis=1) > 5].index)

print(round(100 * (df.isnull().sum() / len(df.index)), 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{marks = marks[marks.isnull().sum(axis=1) < 5]
print(marks.isna().sum())}
```

Please try these this will help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please test your solutions before posting and make sure they address the question and provide an explanation. Your solution does not print the percentages.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://query.data.world/s/Hfu_PsEuD1Z_yJHmGaxWTxvkz7W_b0')
df = df[df.isnull().sum(axis=1)<5]
print(df.isnull().sum())
```